# StartService после разрешения получать уведомлений

Tags: android, service, уведомления

В приложении есть служба,которая работает со startforeground-методом для выполнения службы. Все работает хорошо, но когда пользователь в настройках убирает галочку "разрешить" для принятия уведомлений (notification), естественно, вместе со службой умирают. Как сделать так, если клиент нажимает в настройках галочку, чтобы разрешать принимать уведомления, служба вместе с startforeground возобновляются или перезапускаются?

Comment: Предполагаем ли что пользователь повторно запускает приложение? Если да то мы можем проверять permission на нотификации... и далее проверять, сравнивать.